# HTMLUnit not redirecting to actual webpage

Tags: java, ajax, web-scraping, htmlunit, sourceforge

I am trying to download some files from this site.

The site initially lands at a loading screen later it will redirect to the original site where we need to enter the logins.
But the HTMLUnit is not taking us to the login page.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://eportal.incometax.gov.in/iec/foservices/#/login"), HttpMethod.GET);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);

    HtmlInput htmlInput = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("panAdhaarUserId");
    System.err.println(htmlInput); //it is giving null value 
    System.err.prinln(page.asText()); //it is printing the initial loading screen only
```

Comment: The page content replacements seems to be done by javascript but executing the js inside HtmlUnit seems to fail (Error during JavaScript execution com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: missing ) after formal parameters (https://eportal.incometax.gov.in:443/iec/foservices/scripts.1e24d9a664666fff7c49.js#1)) This usually point to some modern js feature not supported by Rhino (the js engine used in HtmlUnit).

Comment: any other options to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @RBRi , Could you pls share your contact details to discuss on this?

Comment: https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/team.html

Comment: I have mailed this issue to the team few days ago. Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: Sorry, maybe if missed you mail - can you please send again. (Will be on vacation during the next week - please expect no fast progress)

Comment: dear @RBRi , Any update on the above isuue?

Comment: Sorry not really. Have done a lot of work on Rhino during the last months but there is much more to do. And please keep in mind that i'm doing all the stuff in my spare time.

There is a plan to be more independent from core-js and then try to use another more recent js engine. But this is only a plan - maybe i will start on this at the beginning of next year.

Comment: oh, how to add different js engine in htmlunit

Comment: You can't do it now - i have to support that, and that is the plan. At the moment we have many direct dependencies to core-js at various places - i try to reduce this to some minimum and hide the rest behind interfaces. And then i can start.... But keep in mind we have >900 DOM classes with many many properties and method, all these classes have to be touched.

Comment: oh, then it will be a major change